# How to Limit the S3 storage based on folders(prefix)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created a bucket in s3 and then created prefix based on the username of my clients. For every client I want to allocate some space they can use to upload files in s3 or save their results in s3. if space limit exceeds the client will not be able to upload any more file until they delete the old ones.

Does s3 provide space usage limit based on the prefix if not how to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: How are the clients obtaining credentials to upload to S3? Are you giving them S3 credentials, or is your application generating credentials? What are the permissions on the S3 bucket?

Answer (score 0):

There is no ability in Amazon S3 to specify a limit on storage space. This would be the responsibility of your application.

Typically, you would not give clients any credentials for your AWS Account. Instead, they would interact via your application, which can generate [Amazon S3 Presigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) to allow an object to be uploaded. The application can decide whether to allow an upload and can also specify a maximum permitted size within the pre-signed URL.